# Unable to start PSSession

Tags: windows, powershell, winrm

I am trying to start a new remote session, using Powershell, to a server that is part of a dev domain. There is no trust between these two servers.

> [XX-XXX-DB1.didevtest.local] Connecting to remote server
>   XX-XXX-DB1.didevtest.local failed with the following error message :
>   WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified
>   computer name  is valid, that the computer is accessible over the
>   network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is
>   enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM
>   firewall exception  for public profiles limits access to remote
>   computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (XX-XXX-DB1.didevtest.local:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionStateBroken

I have enabled WinRM using `Enable-PSRemoting` and also added my local PC as a trusted system on the remote system using 
`Set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value`.

If I use the IP address of the remote server, I get following error:

> New-PSSession : [XXX.XX.X.X] Connecting to remote server
>   XXX.XX.X.Xfailed with the following error message : The WinRM client
>   cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an
>   IP  address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or
>   the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials
>   are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that 
>   computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For
>   more information on how to set TrustedHosts run the following command:
>   winrm help config. For more information, see the 
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At line:2 char:16
>   + ... motesession=New-PSSession -ComputerName "XXX.XX.X.X" -Credential $cre ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession],
>   PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionOpenFailed Enter-PSSession : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The
>   argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or
>   empty, and then try the command again. At line:3 char:26
>   + Enter-PSSession -Session $remotesession
>   +                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enter-PSSession], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.EnterPSSessionCommand

Comment: What is the full command you use for the connection?

Comment: $credential=Get-Credential -UserName "didevtest.local\xxxxx.txxxs" -Message "Test"
$remotesession=New-PSSession -ComputerName "XX-XXX-DB1.didevtest.local" -Credential $credential -Authentication Default
Enter-PSSession -Session $remotesession

Comment: **"added the my local pc as trusted system on the remote system"** The remote computer needs to be added to TrustedHosts on the local PC.  Additionally, check out the official help docs:  [about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

Add the remote machine to your TrustedHosts list :

Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value $ip -force